# Can't see my new builds in Itunes Connect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, application-loader

I'm trying to upload a new build of my app for the test flight.
All is ok (I tried Application Loader with build 3, and XCode 8 with build 4) but I can't see my builds in ITunes Connect interface at all.

So, it's not a processing status error (where you could see your build but is unable to use it), I just can't see these builds.

At the same time I can't upload the same build again because it is already here. I have this error message (Application Loader and XCode both):

```
ERROR ITMS-4238 Redundant Binary Upload. There already exists a binary upload with build version '4' for train '1.0' at Software Assets/PreReleaseSoftwareAsset
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Just a guess, but have you tried  incrementing the build version? Just based on the error message.

Comment: yes, of course. after problem with build 3, I created build 4.

Comment: Actually, there was one more change. I have in-app purchases in my app, but I blocked them in this build completely. Could it be the reason?

Comment: what do you mean by block here?

Comment: This code was removed/commented. Users aren't able to make any in-app purchases right now (but I still have them in iTunes Connect).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your email inbox, which registered for Apple ID, if the build has a problem, you will receive notification by iTunes Connect.